# What's the difference between 2 Java8 downloads?

Tags: netbeans, download, java-8

I'm about to download and run Java8 with Netbeans, but there seems to be 2 different download files that's confusing me, they seems the same but with different sizes :

1. At https://netbeans.org/downloads/ "Java EE" is the one I want, it's size is 191M and the Java SE's size is 90M.
2. At http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html the size of "Windows x64" is 260M.

Why so much difference ?

I'm running Win7 64bit and I want the Java EE with Netbeans, how do I choose which one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first link will allow you to fetch the NetBeans installer **only** whilst the second link will fetch you the installer **and** the JDK.

If you want both, go for the 2nd link.